# Edit build definition - path over 259 characters

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build, character-limit

I need to edit my solution's build definition to include some new projects. Unfortunately, I can't do that because I keep getting the "path contains more than the  allowed 259 characters" error. I've tried to rename the file to make it shorter - the total path character number is now 257. But I keep getting the same error message and the filename in the message is still the old, long one.

I'm really confused now. The file is located within: 
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\VSTFSBuild...

Does anyone know why the filename remains unchanged in the error message or knows of any other way to fix the problem?

Comment: Are these files part of your workspace?

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of long path issue,  the common workarounds are to [**shorten the build path**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaronhallberg/2007/06/20/team-build-and-260-character-paths/) on the server.

***For example:*** instead of `\xx\Build\Drop\ProjectName`, just use `\xx\Build\Drop` (or `\xx\Builds`) since the project name is also in the build name.

For the long path issue in TFS, there had been a related *uservoice* and now completed.

> [Fix 260 character file name length limitation](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/4954037-fix-260-character-file-name-length-limitation)
>
> We’ve removed the limitation from the BCL for the basic file
>   manipulation functionality (CRUD). You can find more details here:
>
> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/02/announcing-net-framework-4-6-2/
>
> *Immo Landwerth Program Manager .NET*

---

If you are using **XAML** build definition, by default the build control specifies a path for the build to access any custom assemblies your custom build process requires. If you don't have custom assemblies, you don't need this value.

Open **Team Foundation Administration Console** on your Build Server, and click **Properties** on the **build controller**. Remove the path and try to edit the build definition again.

[image]

Comment: The problem is, the error message is complaining about a file on my LOCAL host, not on the TFS. And like I've said, I did change the filename and the path is now below the limit.

Comment: Maybe there is something lock your build definition. Change something in the **Source Settings** tab and go back to the Process tab, it may do the trick. For example, on the Source Settings tab click the Status column of the first blank column and change it to Cloaked, then click off that row, you will notice nothing changed. But now you can go back to the Process tab and check this again.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, I managed to overcome the problem this way:

- go to Process and click OK to the error message when it appears
- click "Show more details" next to my build process template
- click the Refresh button

(I'm using Visual Studio 2012)

Comment: Seems there is some cache or delay lock the build definition.  You could mark this as an answer. Which will help others in this site.